# Jquery replace text inside nested span

Tags: jquery

I have a `span` with id similar to:

```
<span id="xxx" clas="some_classes">
   <span>This text is fixed</span>
   This text can be changed
</span>
```

I need to change the text "This text can be changed" in another text using jquery.

I can't use `$("#xxx").text("My new text");` because the nested span need to stay here.

How can replace only text?

Comment: why not use a span with a class to specify which text can be changed ?

Comment: @DylanKas the code is generated by external plugin. i can't chose how to build it

Comment: You can use .contents() and .filters() to filter on a specified nodeType,

In your case :

    $('#xxx').contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3
    }).each(function(){
        this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('My new Text');
    });